# Access List for which user doesn't have permission

Tags: sharepoint-server, custom-list

I have been trying to access the list and list items for which user doesn't have permissions.

I have restricted the List for the user because I don't want him to see that list neither in Quick Launch Nor in Site Contents.

Can anyone please explain me how can I achieve this.

I have tried `SPSecurity.RunWIthElivatedPrivileges` but this piece of code doesn't work for my requirement.

Comment: what's your issue at using SPSecurity.RunWIthElivatedPrivileges ?

Answer (score 0):

Go to List setting>permission>Break Inheritance and provide unique permission

For ListItem>Select Item>right click, select Share>click on advance>Break Inheritance and provide unique permission

Answer (score 0):

Have you created `SPSite` instance in `Security.RunWIthElivatedPrivileges` block.?

```
 SPSecurity.RunWIthElivatedPrivileges(delegate(){

    using(SPSite site=new SPSite("site url"))       
    {
       using(SPWeb web=site.openWeb())
       {
         //complete your code using site and web object            
       }
    }

})
```